# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-keystore

I know this question has been asked so many times here on the StackOverflow and the solution for this problem was given as "Uninstall previous version and then install"

**My Problem:**

I have made an app for the client and shipp that apk to him he has installed it on his devices. I have delivered him 3 to 4 APK. and all he need to do is to get the Apk and install them (this is a procedure I have made in app by downloading newest version from my server and then installing new version using installer)

Now for some reasons I have to uninstall and intall my Android studio. I also did upgrade it to new version 3.1.  Now that I have to make some changes and I have to ship the new APK in debug mode. I have shipped the APK. but its just not getting installed on client devices. Also I can generate same case on my device.

I can not afford to let the client to do this work (uninstall previous version and then install the newer version)

**What I found on internet?**  I got to know after doing some research on internet. And that is the debug.keystore is the problem. All apks needs to be signed with same certificates and keystore. I have read that its the case with the realsed version of APK but I wonder if it is the case with the debug apk too.

**Any Solution ?** 
Now please tell me If I can get my previous keystore? can I get any thing from previous debug APK ? any solution and work around except installing and uninstalling APK ???? please help

**Note:** 
For some reasons I have not made it release version and I also did not upload it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make a keystore([link here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-apk)) and back it up somewhere safe for all your future releases. Then if you sign it from the same keystore for future builds, you should not run into these issues.

There shouldn't be a reason to ship debug apk unless your client has a specific request because the they are as the name suggests open to debugging by potential attackers.

You should also check [proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard) if you care for security of your apks